# Extract data from meta data field and copy to new field

Tags: managed-metadata, date-time, calculated-column-formula

I have a managed term set which provides date meta data for a column used by accounts.  They tag a document depending on the period (month and year) it relates to.

What I wish to achieve is to have a field containing the YEAR information.  **I am trying to extract this YEAR data from the existing managed metadata column**.

The managed metadata column is contains the date value in the format MMM YY e.g. Jan 18 - **I am trying to grab the 18 from the meta data field and copy it to a new column**.

If I can create a new (calculated?) column to automatically tag each document with the YEAR it would be a good time saver.

[image: screen shot of meta data field]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a way that works, someone else might be able to improve on this though.

I created a new `single line of text` field called **DateText** and I set the default value text, like this:

```
=[Mgmt Accounts Project]
```

[image: DateText field]

Next I made a workflow which triggers when the item is created or modified.

`IF value equals value`   //I've used my meta data 'date' field here.

`SET DateText to Current Item:Value`  //this returns the MMM YY + a load of garbled crap, which needs snipping off), hence the need to clean it up.  Look in the **ACTIONS** menu, scroll all the way to the bottom and select **Extract Substring from Start of String**, I need 6 characters from the current 'dirty data':

`then copy 6 characters from start of Current Item:Value`  //return the value as String.  The workflow holds this as a variable - so I did this:

`Set DateText to [%Variable:substring%]` //which pastes the 6 characters to the DateText field.  That gives me the YY number I need in the DateText field.

[image: Workflow - set Extract Date from meta data field and SET to DateText]

All I need to do then is update my 1000 documents to populate the DateText field.  (See what I mean about it not being perfect?).  Then I create views based on If DateText field contains e.g. 18 for a view for 2018.

Answer (score 0):

If want extract year from Date-time column you use below method

For example you have Date column and you want last 2 character of year for that date column, so you can create calculation column using below formula

```
=RIGHT(YEAR([Created]),2)
```

It will return last 2 character of Created Date year,

i.e.

**Created Date Is 22/01/2018 then output is 18**

Also you can refer this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb862071(v=office.14).aspx)

Comment: Hi Bharat, thanks for the suggestion, it is a good idea.  However, I am limited by the source column I am using - it is a managed metadata field containing date information.  When I create a new Calculated column my managed metadata field is not available for use in a formula.

Comment: Hi Tally, I have updated formula and my Answer please check, Let me know it work for you or not?

Comment: Hi Bharat - this does not work for managed meta data fields, but would work fine for normal field types.  My column is using a range of date values which are managed in Site Settings>Term Store Management.